# Profile fields under Author by field in drupal 7

Tags: 7, entities

I am using Drupal7 and I have created a profile like: *Employee id*, *first name*, *last name* etc ... it is working fine in registration form.
Now when I try to create a node by admin and when I want  give it author by, I need to search from *username*. But I want admin to be able to use *employee id* instead of username.
How to do this?

Thanks